# How do I add keys to a dictionary in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary

Simple question that I can't seem to find an answer to:

How do I add/append a key to a dictionary that resides in a list of dictionaries?

---

Given the list below:

```
list = [{'key-1': 'value-1', 'key-2': 'value-2'}, {'key-A': 'value-A'}]
```

I want to add `'key-B": "value-B'` in the second dictionary for the result to be:

```
list = [{'key-1': 'value-1', 'key-2': 'value-2'}, 
        {'key-A': 'value-A', 'key-B': 'value-B'}]
```

I thought I could just `.update` or `.append` to it but, no such luck.

Any assistance with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Notice that you are overriding the builtin type `list` when using a variable with that name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just do this.

```
list[1]['key-B'] = 'value-B'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
print(list)
[{'key-2': 'value-2', 'key-1': 'value-1'}, {'key-B': 'value-B', 'key-A': 'value-A'}]
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple! Just never had the need for it before. Thanks for the quick and simple reply!

Comment: How can I add the same result but for all dictionaries?

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary don't have any append method, For example if you have a dictionary as

```
dict = {'First':1, 'Second':2},
```

then you can add a third item as

```
dict['Third']=3.
```

Similarly in your case you want to change the second element of your list so **list[1]** will represent your second element and this element is dictionary so you can operate in the same way as dictionary

```
list[1]['key-B'] = 'value-B'
```

Your list has two elements and in this case both are dictionaries. Dictionary do have a update method and if you want to use update of dictionary then first access the dictionary element of your list and then update

```
list[1].update({'key-C':'value-C'})
```

You can check what methods are available using dir(list[1]) in your python interactive shell